# TreeView doesn't have the AfterExpand event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, treeview

I try to have a treeview that browse potentially cyclic hierarchical data.
This means that I cannot try to load all the tree at once, since there maybe be infinite loops then.

I would like to react to the TreeView.AfterCollapse Event documented [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercollapse.aspx)

however, my control doesnt seem to have this event. If I try to add the AfterExpand attribute, i get this error message:

```
 error MC3072: The property 'AfterExpand' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'. Line 23 Position 21.
```

What I am doing wrong ? Calling a wrong namespace ?
Here is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Edit.EditView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Edit"
    Title="{Binding WindowTitle,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinHeight="350" MinWidth="350">

    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="sectionTemplate"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ChildSections}"
        DataType="{x:Type local:Section}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" - " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="#777" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}"
                SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource sectionTemplate}"
                MinHeight="150"
                MinWidth="300"
                Name="treeView"
                AfterExpand="MyEventHandler"
        </TreeView>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Label, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 Margin="0 10 0 0"/>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 Margin="0 10 0 0"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Add Child" Click="Button_Click_AddChild" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I think it is not avilable in wpf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a Windows Forms tree view event, it does not belong to the WPF `TreeView`, in WPF you can use [`Collapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.collapsed.aspx) and [`Expanded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.expanded.aspx) of the `TreeViewItems`, not the `TreeView` itself.

However you can subscribe to the events on the `TreeView` as they are [routed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx).